# AttributeError at /basic_app/register/ : 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: django

I know this question have been asked alot and most of the time its due to render or `HttpResponse` in the `views.py`, i double checked mine but the code looks good to me, dont know where the problem is.

This is a `views.py` file for a very basic django form but i can't get it to work

```
def register(request):


    registered = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(data = request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm(data = request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_from.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            profile = profile_form.save(commit = False)
            profile.user = user

            if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:
                profile.profile_pic = request.FILES['profile_pic']

            profile.save()
            registered = True

        else:
            return (user_form.errors,profile_form.errors)

    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm()

    return render(request,'basic_app/register.html',{'user_form': user_form,                                      
                                                  'profile_form':profile_form,
                                                     'registered':registered})
```

Comment: You can not `return (user_form.errors,profile_form.errors)`. It should be, a HTTP response.

Answer (score 1):

You can not `return (user_form.errors, profile_form.errors)`, since that is not a `HttpResponse` object. What response should the server return in that case.

Usually in case the form is invalid, the server will rerender the content. The form will, if you render it properly display the errors.

Note that in case the POST request was successful, you usually should redirect to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). You furthermore probably want to use a [**`UserCreationForm`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm). This will set the password of the user in the correct way (with `.set_password(..)`), and run a password validator if you configured this.

You thus can rewrite your view as follows, but you probably should replace `UserForm`  with `UserCreationForm`:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm(data=request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = user_from.save(commit=False)
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()
            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user

            if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:
                profile.profile_pic = request.FILES['profile_pic']

            profile.save()
            return redirect('name-of-view')
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm()

    return render(
        request,
        'basic_app/register.html',
        {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form':profile_form })
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I read both the articles and i learnt new things. But i kinda started a week ago so dont know much. Could you please tell me why would the is_valid() even get Fasle? Effort appreciated

Comment: @AnasNisar: for exampel because required POST parameters are missing, or an integer field contains `'blabla'`. A html form does not guarantee a valid POST request, since a hacker can for example make a milicious POST request.

Comment: Oh okay.. thanx alot1